# Active X checkboxes in word, glitching

Tags: vba, checkbox, activex, ms-word

So I have some Active x check boxes on my word document which all have code tied to them and text next to them as well.
When I scroll they seem to have a graphical glitch, in which the text size goes smaller whilst scrolling then returns to normal when stopping.

Anyone know how to fix this?
It is making my supposed "professional" document look pretty naff.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Microsoft Word vs. ActiveX controls, possibly introduced by some update - I guess you could file a complaint at Microsoft, or try to find an alternative, e.g. I think I'd try removing the text from the ActiveX controls (leaving only the box) and using actual text instead.

Comment: You wouldn't be suggesting that if you knew how many there were :(
If nothing else i guess i'll have to do that, thanks.